# Is it possible to copy and paste data from an opened excel window, which is defined as remote (//Remote)?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

Is it possible to copy and paste data from an opened excel window, which is defined as remote (//Remote) because it is apparently/probably on another server?

I normally searched for and set the workbook like this:

```
For beginoutput = 1 To 9999
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbook = Workbooks("info" & reeks & ".csv)
    If wbook Is Nothing Then
        Set wbook = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0
        reeks = reeks + 1
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next beginoutput
```

But the data I use now resides on another server I think, because when I open it, my code does not work anymore, while the excel windows are next to each other on my screen.

If i check the source it shows a difference in filepaths (between the active workshoot and the worksheet with the information I need), which changes per user, so i cannot use pathway to copy and paste the required data.

Comment: If you take out the `On Error Resume Next`, you'll probably get a better indication of what "does not work".

Comment: Your code is missing a quotation mark `Set wbook = Workbooks("info" & reeks & ".csv)` should be `Set wbook = Workbooks("info" & reeks & ".csv")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why that WOULDN'T work.  Can you turn on the Macro Recorder and click through the process?  You should get all the code you need, and a whole lot more too.